# Function to print integer in GLUT - How to write a function for int to char conversion?

Tags: c, string, glut

I am learning C, but everything became too abstract at some point, so I decided to use OpenGL to be able to try more concrete things involving user interaction. I am also trying to ensure my code is portable, so I always run it on my Mac Pro, on a Raspberry Pi and on an old Power Mac.

I have created a small colour table to help my life:

```
GLfloat white[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat red[3] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat green[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat blue[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat yellow[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat dark_gray[3] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 };
```

And the following function to print text:

```
void printText(char *text, const GLfloat colour[3], float posX, float posY) {
    glColor3fv (colour);
    glRasterPos2f(posX, posY);
  
    while(*text){
       glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, *text++);
    }
```

}

Which I call this way, for example: `printText(fn, white, 0.90f, 0.92f);`
And it works great!

I'm doing a integer to string conversion to print to screen a frame rate counter, based on code I found here in the forum, and I think I understand well what it is doing:

```
int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", frame_number );
char *fn = malloc( length + 1 );
snprintf(fn, length + 1, "%d", frame_number );
printText(fn, white, 0.90f, 0.92f);
```

I don't want to write all this code every time I want to print an integer to the screen, but nothing that I do works.

```
char charToInt(int integer) {
int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", integer);
char *convertedInteger = malloc(length + 1);
snprintf(convertedInteger, length + 1,"%d", integer);
return convertedInteger;}
```

OR `return *convertedInteger;` both crash when I try to call `printText(convertedInteger,colour,posX,posY);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `char *charToInt(int integer)`? (Note the star, but you should get a warning. Perhaps it's just a typo in the question.)

Comment: A lot of GLUT programmes do this exact thing.

Comment: @MOehm
not a typo. It's been working like this. XCode doesn't throw in any warnings.

Comment: @Neil 
I don't intend to become a GLUT programmer. I really just need a portable way to write more dynamic information on the screen. =)

Thank you both.

Comment: Hm. But you are returning a value of type `char *` from a function that returns `char`. That should give you an "implicit pointer conversion" warning. (Unfortunately, most C compiler require you to activate warnings explicitly, for example `gcc -Wall` or `cl /Wall`. I don't know XCode, but I guess it has a setting for that.

Comment: @MOehm No warning. I have it out of the box, no extra settings. I see what you say makes sense, but I'm really just beginning. If I do the change you suggested, am I going to break the code?

Comment: The code is already broken. `convertedInteger` is a pointer, 32 or 64 bits. By returning a `char`, you reduce it to an 8-bit value. It is very, very likely that this will corrupt your pointer. Accesing it from `printText` will then cause a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out:

This is how I call it:
`GLprintTextAndInteger("just a bunch of words", int_to_print, colour, posX, posY);`

And this is the function:

```
void GLprintTextAndInteger (char *text, int value, float colour[3], float posX, float posY) {
int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %i", text, value);
char *stringToPrint = malloc(length + 1);
snprintf(stringToPrint, length + 1, "%s %i",text,value);
printText(stringToPrint,colour,posX,posY);
free(printText);
}
```

Then it calls the function I mention in the question correctly:

```
void printText(char *text, const GLfloat colour[3], float posX, float posY) {
glColor3fv (colour);
glRasterPos2f(posX, posY);

while(*text){
   glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, *text++);
}
```

Thank you all!

Edit: freeing memory to avoid leak as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You should `free(stringToPrint)` after calling `printText`, otherwise you will leak small chunks of memory every time you call your function. In fact, you don't need to allocate memory on the heap. The "longest" integer (in terms of characters) you can print is about −2,000,000,000. Just create a local array `char tmp[20]` and `sprint` into that.

Comment: Thank you! I will fix that.